# I cannot use deluge as usual

Tags: deluge

I use Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop x64.

I use deluge normally to download torrents but today deluge crashed and then stopped downloading (error)
The status says: **desync.com: Error: Bad file descriptor**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is not **Deluge**. I tell you what would be the possible reason:

1. You added torrents in Deluge and give some path say in drive `/dev/sdaX`.
2. You restart you system and when Deluge is opened you get the error!!
3. The drive `/dev/sdaX` is not mounted automatically until you go to your file manager and mount it by clicking on it.
4. Since you opened Deluge before mounting `dev/sdaX` drive obviously it will give you the error because there is no such place in which you added your torrent. So you've to make available that path.

**Now what you can do!!**

1. Check whether the drive in which your torrents are downloading is being mounted.
2. If not mounted first close **Deluge** and **mount** the drive.
3. Then open **Deluge** and **force re-check** for the torrents you added for downloading.

Hope this would be your problem as it happened with me already. Reply what happens..

Comment: Am a beginner I don't know how to mount the drive. I used an unreliable site to download and then deluge crashed

Comment: @Marco: hey mounting means just opening the drive for read/write. You can easily mount using any **file manager**. Just open any one, on the left side you'll see the list of your drives and other links like Home, Documents, Downloads, Music, Picture etc.. Just click on the drive you want to mount. It will be mounted and opened. The small **Up** like icon will notify that it has been mounted. Hope you can understand now.

Comment: Thanx a lot But now it's worse. deluge speed is very slow No more than 6 kbps maximum. It used to be 700 kbps to 1 MBps

Comment: Sorry for being sticky but now it's ok since I increased speed manually. Thanx a lot